# Laravel get route with parameter in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I need to get the route in my view for redirecting.

Right now I'm doing this:
[Laravel 4 - Get Current Route Name on Hidden Input to use for search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877121/laravel-4-get-current-route-name-on-hidden-input-to-use-for-search)

```
{{ Form::hidden('route', Route::current()->getUri()) }}
```

Problem is, it looks like this when I get on a page with an id:

```
<input name="route" type="hidden" value="recipes/details/{id}">
```

How can I parse the {id} variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
Request::url();
```

Instead of  `Route::current()->getUri()`, but it's not proper way to redirect from the `View`, you should redirect from your `Controller` instead.

It should be in your case (for full url):

```
 // 'http://example.com/recipes/details/10'
{{ Form::hidden('route', Request::url()) }}
```

or use this (only for path):

```
 // 'recipes/details/10'
{{ Form::hidden('route', Request::path()) }}
```

Comment: No, I just need the current rout in the login controller, because I'm loggin in via an overlay and it always redirects me to the open overlay... that is not good.